# Android hidden layout buttons behind soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

I'm developing an application which needs user enter some words into. But as soon as keyboard opening my layout buttons in bottom of layout remain behind soft keyboard.

My app is here

[image]

I need my buttons remains showing when soft keyboard opening.

[image]

Here is my layout resource file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d3d3d3" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llWord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblWord"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/string_word"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#555555" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtWord"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@null"
            android:text="@null"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblInfo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@null"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#555555" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMeaning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/string_meaning"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#555555" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMeaning"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@null"
            android:text="@null"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSynonyms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/string_synonyms"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#555555" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSynonyms"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@null"
            android:text="@null"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_undo"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/action_show"
        android:textColor="#d3d3d3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTrue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/action_true"
        android:textColor="#d3d3d3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFalse"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_remove"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/action_false"
        android:textColor="#d3d3d3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried using adjustPan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to AndroidManifest.xml , add this to your Activity declare:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```